# How do I get all the optimal solutions from my linear programming with pyscipopt?

Tags: python, linear-programming, scip, pyscipopt

How do I get all the optimal solutions from my linear programming with pyscipopt?
I just want to display them(using print()).

I see that my Linear Programming has several optimal feasible solutions. However, I can only view one. The function model.getNBestSolsFound() gives me the number of optimal solutions.

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

@user22146991! You can use `print(model.getSols())` to get what you wanted.

Sometimes (I suspect it's whenever the trivial heuristic solves the problem) PySCIPOpt can't print the solutions, but they're still there. You can iterate through the solution and then, in each solution, iterate through the variables.

EDIT: This answer assumes that SCIP manages to find all the optimal solutions you want since it stops the solving process as soon as it proves the optimality of a solution, as discussed in the comments.

Comment: You should note that SCIP does not try to find all the optimal solutions, it will stop as soon as it has found ONE optimal solution.

Comment: Ah, of course, I misread the question. Thanks, @Leon!